# php get all disk linux ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-12.04

i want get disk server

i used commands php:

```
putenv('PATH='. getenv('PATH') .':/home/');

$command_exec = exec("fdisk -l", $output, $result); 

var_dump($output);
```

==> array(0) { }

Can anyone guide me.

thanks !

Comment: Why would you add `/home` to `PATH`?

Comment: I want to go out root directory.

Comment: If that is supposed to mean you want to change directories, that's not how you do that.  Appending a directory to `PATH` affects where (some of the members of) the `exec` family of system calls look for executables.  For example, if `php` is in `/usr/bin` and that directory is in your `PATH`, the command `php` works (whereas otherwise you would have to say `/usr/bin/php` explicitly).

Comment: if you know. you can help and please do not vote. because I do not know this new up to need help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. `fdisk` is in `/sbin`, you may need to add that to `PATH`.
2. `fdisk -l` doesn't show anything unless it's run by the superuser. If you're running the script from the webserver, it doesn't run as root.

Comment: Can you tell me more.

Comment: That's all I can think of at the moment.

Comment: thank you. i will test commands /sbin 

putenv('PATH='. getenv('PATH') .':/sbin');

==>array(0) { } 

:D